# Maximum number of Red nodes in Red-black tree?

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

Lets assume there is a Red-Black tree. the black height of it is h.

What will be the maximum number of Red nodes in the tree as a function of h?

Comment: This is not a programming question, try a different stack exchange!

Answer (score 0):

The **maximum number of red links** in a red-black BST with N nodes is **~1/2 N**.

Consider a 2-3 tree containing N nodes, all of which are 3-nodes. The corresponding red-black BST has 2N nodes and N red links (one corresponding to each 3-node).

I hope this answers your question.